# jCarousel show item with class selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, jcarousel

I have a list of items with one of them that have `class=selected`, every `n` second change the `class=selected` to the next item.

How can I activate the `jCarousel` scrolling and showing always the item with `class=selected`?

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be easyer to set an autoscroll on the jcarousel?

You can find the information here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

property: "auto"
Specifies how many seconds to periodically autoscroll the content. If set to 0 (default) then autoscrolling is turned off.

You won't need extra coding to change the class to "selected"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jcarousel scroll](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#reference-api-scroll) method like this:

```
var link = $("#linkIWantToScrollTo");

var scrollTo = link.parent().attr("jcarouselindex");
var animateScrolling = true;

// Using jcarousel instance from the element where you applied jcarousel, scroll it...
$("#menu").jcarousel('scroll', scrollTo - 1, animateScrolling, function(scrolled) {
        if (scrolled) {
            console.log('The carousel has been scrolled');
        } else {
            console.log('The carousel has not been scrolled');
        }
 });
```

**Note**: it's necessary to use `scrollTo - 1` because [index is 0 based](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/usage.html#reference-usage-navigating-the-carousel-target-formats). Otherwise you'll get undesired results! :)

`link` is an anchor `<a>` like this one:

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-8 jcarousel-item-8-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;" jcarouselindex="14">
<a id="linkIWantToScrollTo" title="Educação de Pacientes e Familiares" href="#">
</li>
```

With the above code `jcarousel` will scroll to position `14`. This is working great right now in one of my projects. Position `14` was out of sight and applying the scroll method allows a great user experience since the item will be in sight.